# LocalDate and LocalDateTime in a server which runs in EST vs UTC

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, utc, localdate

I am trying to understand LocalDate and LocalDateTime. Since they do not carry zone info, how does it work for now() on two different time zone.

Example:

Server 1(EST time zone):

LocalDateTime.now() -> 2020-04-06T23:00:00.040
LocalDate.now(). -> 2020-04-06

Server 2(UTC time zone):

LocalDateTime.now() -> What would be the value?
LocalDate.now(). -> What would be the value? (Note in EST, time it executed was 11 PM)

Also,
If I convert below date string to LocalDateTime and then toLocalDate, what would be the outcome?

2020-04-06T23:00:00.000

Comment: what do you mean what would be the value? what is the difference between `EST` and `UTC`?

Comment: EST is 5 hr behind UTC

Comment: What do you expect the local times to be in UTC, other than 5 hours ahead?

Comment: It seems from the comments that your use of *EST* has caused a bit of confusion. First, EST is ambiguous, as many three letter time zone abbreviations are. It could mean Australian Eastern Standard Time or North American Eastern Standard Time. Second, most of the places using North American EST don’t do that on April 6, they use Eastern Daylight Time (EDT) instead. Implying (1) EST is not really a time zone. (2) There was doubt whether you just meant *Eastern Time*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Offsets vary over time

On April 6, 2020, most time zones on the east coast of North America such as `America/Montreal` and `America/New_York` use an offset of four hours behind UTC.

So, in those zones 11 PM on 2020-04-06 is simultaneously 3 AM on the 7th in UTC. Add four hours to 2020-04-06T23:00 to get 2020-04-07T03:00. Adding four hours brings us from the wall-clock time used in `America/Port-au-Prince` and `America/Nassau` to UTC.

The offset used by the time zones mentioned above are four hours behind UTC only half the year. The politicians in those locations have decided to observe Daylight Saving Time (DST) for about half the year. So half the year they jump their clocks ahead an hour for an offset-from-UTC of -04:00, and later in the year they fall back an hour for an offset-from-UTC of -05:00. For example, earlier in the year 11 PM in `America/New_York` would be 04:00 in UTC rather than the 03:00 time seen in April.

Standard time, in January, is *five* hours behind UTC. So, 11 PM plus five hours is 4 AM next day.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2020 , 1 , 6 , 23 , 0 , 0 , 0 , zNewYork ) ; 
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // 2020-01-07T04:00Z
```

Daylight Saving Time, in April, is *four* hours behind UTC. So, 11 PM plus four hours is 3 AM next day.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2020 , 4 , 6 , 23 , 0 , 0 , 0 , zNewYork ) ; 
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // 2020-04-07T03:00Z
```

By the way, DST is only one of many reasons politicians have for changing the offset used by the time zone(s) of their jurisdiction. Politicians around the world have shown a penchant for changing their offsets surprisingly often. Your programming should always expect a time zone to change its offset. Just because your particular zone of concern does not currently observe DST does *not* mean the offset will never change.

As for parsing `2020-04-06T23:00:00.000` as a `LocalDateTime`, you will get `2020-04-06T23:00:00.000`. Ignoring time zones is the entire point of `LocalDateTime`. So no adjustments are made.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

You may be thinking of `LocalDateTime` as representing a particular locality. But, no, it represents *any* locality or *all* localities. But never any one particular locality. For a particular locality, use `ZonedDateTime`.

## Pseudo time zones

Another point: `EST` is *not* a time zone. Such 2-4 letter letter codes are not real time zones, are not standardized, and are not even unique. For example, by `EST`, did you mean *Australian Eastern Standard Time* or *North American Eastern Standard Time*? Is `CST` *Central Standard Time* or *China Standard Time*? Avoid these pseudo-zones in your date-time-handling.

And you happened to use the wrong pseudo-code. On April 6 2020, most of those east coast time zones are observing Daylight Saving Time (DST). So they would be considered to be in “EDT” rather than “EST”. Avoid the problem by specifying the real time zone name.

Real time zones are named using `Continent/Region` format. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for a list of real time zones.

## Never call `LocalDateTime.now`

I cannot imagine a case where calling `LocalDateTime.now` would be the right thing to do. Determining the current moment requires a time zone (or offset). And `LocalDateTime` by definition has no time zone or offset. When a programmer writes `LocalDateTime.now`, you can bet they do not fully understand the necessary concepts.

When you call `LocalDateTime.now`, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly used to capture the current time as seen by the people in the region of that zone. And then the fact of that time zone is deleted.

This:

```
LocalDateTime.now()
```

…is the same as this:

```
LocalDateDate.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() )
```

…which is the same as getting the current moment as seen in a particular time zone, followed by removing the time zone information:

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ).toLocalDateTime()
```

For more code examples demonstrating `LocalDateTime.now`, see the [correct Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61061492/642706)

## Where to use `LocalDateTime`

If `LocalDateTime` is not appropriate for getting the current moment, and is not appropriate for tracking any moment, what is the appropriate use for this class? Three things: representing any locality, representing all localities, and booking future appointments.

- Any locality would be something like stating when Christmas starts. This year Christmas starts at 2020-12-25T00:00 wherever you are in the world. Of course this means Christmas starts first in Kiribati after midnight, later in Japan after midnight, even later in Tunisia after midnight, and still later in Chicago after midnight.
- All localities would be something like stating our company policy that lunch breaks at all our factories in Delhi, Düsseldorf, and Detroit are scheduled for 12:30. So on April 6 2020, the break will be at 2020-04-06T12:30:00. This break will occur first in Delhi, several hours later in Düsseldorf, and even more hours later in Detroit.
- Booking future appointments where you intend to keep the same time-of-day regardless of changes to the time zone’s offset must recorded without the offset. If your next dental appointments is in six months at 3 PM, we want to record the 3 PM without regard for the offset. If the offset were to be changed by politicians, we still want the appointment to start when the clock strikes three on that date in that zone.

Set the appointment.

```
LocalDateTime appointment = LocalDateTime.of( 2021 , 1 , 23 , 15 , 0 , 0 , 0 ) ;
```

Determine a moment for producing a calendar. Every time you do this, you may get a different result if the politicians have changed the rules of this time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "America/Panama" ) ;
ZonedDateTime dueToArrive = appointment.atZone( z ) ;
```

## `LocalDate`

As for `LocalDate`, we saw in the examples above that the date depends on time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. It may be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while still “yesterday” in Montréal Québec Canada.

So, you must specify a time zone when asking for the current date.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) ;
```

If you omit the time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. So `LocalDate.now()` becomes `LocalDate.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() )`. I recommend specifying your desired/expected zone explicitly, rather than rely on implicit default.

## Server time zone

You said:

> server which runs in EST vs UTC

FYI, servers should generally be set to UTC. Most of your thinking, programming, logging, and so on should be done in UTC. Learn to think of UTC as The One True Time, with all other zones but mere variations.

As a programmer, you should never rely on the default time zone. That is far outside your control. That default can be changed so easily by the user or sysadmin. Furthermore, any code in any thread of any app within the JVM can instantly change the JVM’s current default time with a call to `TimeZone.setDefault`. So even *during* execution of your app, the default can be changed at any moment.

Comment: I think that the correct way to put this would be that: _During Daylight Saving Time_ , this is 4 hours difference.

Comment: @OleV.V. indeed, but from the comments OP and Andy Turner seems to seemed to miss that.

Comment: If we take `EST` to mean strictly North American Standard Time, those comments are correct too, @Eugene. A few places use EST all year, just a few. See the list [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/est).

Comment: @OleV.V. exactly - I am in one of those, so _for me_ those 5 hours are not correct and need a proper explanation. I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 5):

To prevent confusion pass explicit time zone to `now()` and see for yourself:

```
    ZoneId easternTime = ZoneId.of("America/Montreal");
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(easternTime));
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    System.out.println(LocalDate.now(easternTime));
    System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

Output when I ran just now:

> ```
> 2020-04-06T09:56:17.381558
> 2020-04-06T13:56:17.385215
> 2020-04-06
> 2020-04-06
> ```

While you are correct that `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate` don’t contain any time zone information, their `now` methods do use time zones. Either the one passed to them, or if you use the no-arg variant, the default time zone of the JVM.

You also asked:

> Also, If I convert below date string to LocalDateTime and then
>   toLocalDate, what would be the outcome?
>
> 2020-04-06T23:00:00.000

Why not try out that too?

```
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-04-06T23:00:00.000");
    System.out.println(ldt);
    LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate();
    System.out.println(ld);
```

> ```
> 2020-04-06T23:00
> 2020-04-06
> ```

Converting from `LocalDateTime` to `LocalDate` involves no time zone (or UTC offset) whatsoever. The time part is simply discarded and the date part kept unchanged.